# How to print strings with floats using Arduino's Serial.println

Tags: c++, string, casting, arduino

I've been printing a combination of strings and numbers with Arduino's Serial.println() like:

```
Serial.println(((String)"some value: " + some_value);
```

And this seems to work for most types, but fails for floats, which give me the compilation error:

ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘String’ and ‘float’)

I've tried different calls like:

```
Serial.println(((String)"some float:" + ((String)some_float));
Serial.println(((String)"some float: " + String(some_float));
Serial.println(((String)"some float: " + String(some_float, 2));
```

but they give similar errors. Arduino's docs on [String](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor) seem to imply that these should work. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

After correcting my original errors, I now have this issue:

```
Serial.println(String("some value: ") + String(some_value));
>> call of overloaded ‘String(float&)’ is ambiguous
```

I also tried:

```
Serial.println(String("some float: ") + String(some_float, 2));
>> call of overloaded ‘String(float&, int)’ is ambiguous
```

Comment: It's not recommended to edit the question to fit the replies, otherwise people who read the question later (like me) will get no idea on why someone answered it. Just leave the original question, then add an EDIT string and put the modifications, explaining why you modified and why it does not work (for instance "I copied it wrong the first time but this is the code I used and it has the same error")

Comment: @frarugi, I agree. However, my question had errors that were confusing people, and the solutions provided were wrong.

Comment: yes, but now it's much more readable, hence the answers can be more precise

Comment: I posted an answer. Maybe something else is wrong, since the code I posted works

Answer (score 1):

It should be something else. I tried now with an Arduino UNO this code:

```
float some_float;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  some_float = 13.3558;
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(String("some float: ") + String(some_float, 2));
  delay(1000);
}
```

and the output is

```
some_float: 13.35
some_float: 13.35
some_float: 13.35
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an extra open bracket in all of your tests.

Next, as the error says, you are attempting to add a float value to a String type.  The docs say the + operator only supports adding two String types together.

You'll need to convert your float into a String then add the two Strings together.  There is an example of this on the doc page you linked:

String stringOne =  String(5.698, 3);  // using a float and the decimal places

The last example you gave that gives 'similar errors' looks like it should work when you remove the extra open bracket, according to the docs.

EDIT: in reference to the new error message ">> call of overloaded ‘String(float&)’ is ambiguous" can you paste some additional code to show at least:
- the definitions of some_float and some_value
- any namespaces you are including (e.g. std etc)
Generally with these sorts of problems, you should reduce the code to the simplest example which shows the error and post that whole example in the thread. (Quite often when you reduce it to the simplest example, you learn what the problem is anyway!)

The error says that String(float&) is *ambiguous*, so I'm guessing you have another namespace with a String definition in it which is conflicting with the Arduino version.

Comment: The open brackets are a typo in my post, but not my code. I'd be getting a very different error otherwise. That code still does not work.

Comment: Can you provide one of the 'similar' errors from the third alternative line? Serial.println(String("some float: ") + String(some_float, 2));